Accumulation points of product sequence
Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two bounded real-valued sequences.
Then if $a$ is an accumulation point of $a_n$ and $b$ an accumulation point of $B$, it is clear that $ab$ is an accumulation point of $a_n b_n$. Indeed, there exist subsequences $a_{n_j}$ and $b_{n_k}$ converging to $a$ and $b$ respectively, and so (by taking further subsequences) we may assume these to be the same subsequence, hence the product $a_{n_j}b_{n_k}\to ab$.
It follows that if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the sets of accumulation points of $a_n$, $b_n$, and $a_n b_n$ respectively, then
$$C\subseteq AB.$$
Question 1: Is the reverse inclusion $AB\subseteq C$ true?
Question 2: If the answer to Q1 is no, then does $AB\subseteq C$ hold when $a_n$ is convergent?
Thoughts: In the case that one of the sequences is allowed to be unbounded, even the first inclusion fails; say if $a_n=n$ and $b_n=1/n$, then $A=\emptyset$, $B=\{0\}$, so $AB=\emptyset$ but $C=\{1\}$.

Let $a_{2n} = 0, b_{2n-1} = 0$ and $a_{2n-1} = a, b_{2n} = b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R \setminus {0}$ and all $n \ge 1$. Then, $A = {0,a}, B = {0,b}$ so $AB = {0,ab}$ but $C = { 0}$ since always $a_nb_n = 0$. You can make analogous examples with different sets $A,B$ by dividing $\mathbb N$ into different sets than even/odd integers.

Nice example, thank you.


Then if $a$ is an accumulation point of $a_n$ and $b$ an accumulation point of $B$, it is clear that $ab$ is an accumulation point of $a_n b_n$.

If it were true, it would show that $AB \subset C$, not $C \subset AB$. Thus you actually address question 1 in this argument.

... and so (by taking further subsequences) we may assume these to be the same subsequence, hence the product $a_{n_j}b_{n_k}\to ab$.

This is not true, the "same subsequence" argument is invalid. A counterexample was given in a comment by Dominik Kutek. Let us repeat it:
$a_{2n} = b_{2n-1} = 0, a_{2n-1} = b_{2n} = 1$. Then $A = B  =\{0,1\}$ and $C = \{0\}$ since $a_nb_n = 0$ for all $n$.
Thus $AB \not\subset C$ which shows that the answer to question 1 is "no".
The answer to question 2 is "yes".
Let $a_n \to a$. If $b \in B$, then there exists a subsequence $(b_{n_k})$ with $b_{n_k} \to b$. Thus $a_{n_k}b_{n_k} \to ab$ which shows $ab \in C$. Thus $AB \subset C$.
Let us finally prove that $C \subset AB$ is always true.
If $c  \in C$, then there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k}b_{n_k})$ with $a_{n_k}b_{n_k} \to c$. Since $(a_n)$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_{k_r}})$ which converges to some $a \in \mathbb R$. Clearly $a \in A$. We have again $a_{n_{k_r}}b_{n_{k_r}} \to c$. If $a = 0$, then $c = 0$ since $b_{n_{k_r}}$ is bounded. Thus $c \in  AB$. If $a \ne 0$, then $b_{n_{k_r}} \to c/a$ which shows $c/a \in B$. Thus $c \in AB$.
